# string highlighter support diacritics and accents javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight, diacritics

Hello i posted before question about this subject but no one responded so Im gonna put simple example of what i trying to do

I created a simple highlighter that supports accents and diacritics as this code example:

```
<div id="text">selection مُحَمّد séléction SÉLÉCTION محمد محمد</div>

.highlight {
background-color:yellow;  
color:red;
}

//var input ="مُحَمّد";
var input = "SÉLÉCTION";

var t = $("#text").html();
var words =  t.split(' ');

function Normlise(s) {
                        var r=s.toLowerCase();
                       //var r=s;
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[\u064b-\u0653\u0670]", 'g'),"");
                        //r = r.replace(new RegExp("\\s", 'g'),"");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[é]", 'g'),"e");
                        //r = r.replace(new RegExp("\\W", 'g'),"");
                        return r; 

                };


        var replacement = function(resultText) {
        var resultText="";
    for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var strippedWord = Normlise(words[i]);
        var inputWord = Normlise(input);


           if (strippedWord == inputWord) {
           alert(strippedWord);

           resultText += ' '+"<span class='highlight'>"+ words[i]+"</span>"+' ';
           }            
           else 
           {
           resultText += ' '+ words[i]+' ';
           }
        }

         return resultText;
        }   

$("#text").replaceWith(replacement);
```

you can check the script online to see how its works 
http://jsfiddle.net/Aku4y/16/
now when come to highlight accents characters we use class map  that defined all the needed characters but what about combined marks diacritics like in the Arabic that is attached with some character how we could make the right regex or class map for it rather than to strip it and compare it as in the example above can someone plz show me an example of fastest way ?? 
thanks